# Iterating through fields with specific attribute

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I'm pretty new to reflection in C#. I want to create a specific attribute that I can use with my fields, so I can go through them all and check that they are initialized properly, instead of writing these checks every time for every field. I think it would look something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass {

    public void Awake() {

        foreach(var s in GetAllFieldsWithAttribute("ShouldBeInitialized")) {

            if (!s) {

                Debug.LogWarning("Variable " + s.FieldName + " should be initialized!");
                enabled = false;

            }

        }

    }

}

public class ChildClass : BasicClass {

    [ShouldBeInitialized]
    public SomeClass someObject;

    [ShouldBeInitialized]
    public int? someInteger;

}
```

(You may notice that I intend to use it Unity3d, but there's nothing specific to Unity in this question — or at least, it seems so to me). Is this possible?

Comment: Does System.Attribute.IsDefined(FieldInfo, Type) exist in unity?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks — I think that I'll be able to google my way out of this, but still not exactly sure how to work with it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this with a simple expression:

```
private IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetAllFieldsWithAttribute(Type attributeType)
{
    return this.GetType().GetFields().Where(
        f => f.GetCustomAttributes(attributeType, false).Any());
}
```

Then change your call to:

```
foreach(var s in GetAllFieldsWithAttribute(typeof(ShouldBeInitializedAttribute)))
```

You can make this more useful throughout your app by making it an extension method on `Type`:

```
public static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetAllFieldsWithAttribute(this Type objectType, Type attributeType)
{
    return objectType.GetFields().Where(
        f => f.GetCustomAttributes(attributeType, false).Any());
}
```

You would call this as:

```
this.GetType().GetAllFieldsWithAttribute(typeof(ShouldBeInitializedAttribute))
```

**Edit**: To get private fields, change `GetFields()` to:

```
GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
```

And to get the type (inside your loop):

```
object o = s.GetValue(this);
```

Comment: How can I get values of these fields? Also, strangely, it seems that the base class sees child's fields only if they are declared public — I tried protected and internal, but then it just ignores them.