# A lot of fields with the same attribute

Tags: c#, syntax, coding-style, attributes

I find myself writing a lot of this kind of stuff:

```
[SameAttribute]
ClassA fieldA;

[SameAttribute]
ClassB fieldB;

[SameAttribute]
ClassC fieldC;

...
```

Is there a syntax in C# that would allow me to mark several fields with the same attribute at once? May be there are coding conventions about this situation that would make this code less verbose and more readable?

Edit: Just to clarify, I don't want *every* field of the class to have this attribute, there's just a lot of them.

Comment: What is your current attribute? What is SameAttribute actually?

Comment: This one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621044/iterating-through-fields-with-specific-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. You will have to apply the `[SameAttribute]` to each field individually.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `SomeAttribute` to apply to all fields in a class, it might be possible to apply the attribute to the entire class. However, even if `SomeAttribute` is allowed to target classes, its exact behavior when doing so is dependent on the implementation of `SomeAttribute`. Otherwise no, you have to apply the attribute to each field individually.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers above, [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/), which allows "aspect-oriented programming" lets you define attributes that will apply to each member in a class. You can use it to make a custom attribute that would apply your desired attribute to all of the members.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing out of the box, that I know of, but you could use a Visual Studio add-in like ReSharper to create a live template to automatically add the Attribute you wish to use when you use a certain template

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html